# htaccess rewrite rule to hide actual file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is my folder structure

```
htdocs
-> testing
   ->index.php
   ->.htaccess
```

Inside index.php I have this code

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])) {
        echo $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
    }
?>
```

Inside .htaccess I have this code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

**Here is my question:**

In the above htaccess rewrite rule, which will link my address localhost/testing/HelloWorld to localhost/testing/index.php/HelloWorld

Is it possible to do some thing like this? When the user enter **localhost/testing/index.php/HelloWorld** I want the browser to hide the word index.php and only display something like this **localhost/testing/HelloWorld**

I tried to redirect the link **localhost/testing/index.php/HelloWorld** to **localhost/testing/HelloWorld** by adding another rule in .htacces file but I get "The webpage has redirect loop" error message.

After I add in new rule the .htacces file looks like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.+)$ /testing/$1 [R]
```

Does any ways that I could make my link like this? Thanks in advanced, your help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the redirect loop, because the rewritten url matches the rule for redirection. You'll need to use a trick to make the external redirect only happen on an external request with index.php, not on an internal rewrite that maps a different request to that file. You can do this with `%{THE_REQUEST}` which will only ever be whatever the external request was. It will not update if you rewrite the file it maps to.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /testing/index\.php/
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.+)$ /testing/$1 [R]
```